# Can't create character chain with spaces

Tags: c++

I need create a character chain with spaces on the variables "NombreMedico" and "Domicilio" i tried cin.get line and i get the error: error: expected primary-expression before 'char', this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class medico
{
public:;

int CodigoMedico ;
char Cedula  ;
int RFC ;
char NombreMedico [100] ;
char Domicilio  ;
int MTelefono  ;


void CapturarDatos()
{
cout<<"Introduce codigo del medico"<<endl;
cin>>CodigoMedico;
cout<<"Introduce cedula del medico"<<endl;
cin>>Cedula;
cout<<"Introduce RFC"<<endl;
cin>>RFC;
cout<<"Introduce nombre del medico"<<endl;
cin.getline (NombreMedico, char [100]);
cout<<"Introduce domicilio del medico"<<endl;
cin.getline (Domicilio, char[100]);
cout<<"Introduce telefono del medico"<<endl;
cin>>MTelefono;
}
void MostrarDatos()

{
cout<<CodigoMedico<<endl;
cout<<Cedula<<endl;
cout<<RFC<<endl;
cout<<NombreMedico<<endl;
cout<<Domicilio<<endl;
cout<<MTelefono<<endl;
}

};

int main()

{
    medico a;
a.CapturarDatos();
a.MostrarDatos();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to cancel **-1** until post is indented.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of a naked arrays to store strings.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
cin.getline (NombreMedico, char [100]);
```

should be

```
cin.getline (NombreMedico, 100);
```